# Suppress parenthesis in r reactable group aggregation

Tags: r, reactjs

I'm using R's reactable package to create a datatable grouped by a specific variable. This displays a collapsed table that can be expanded to show sub-rows. The collapsed row titles have a set of parenthesis next to them to indicate how many sub-rows are nested underneath. Is it possible to suppress this set of parenthesis so that it doesn't display? It is going to confuse my users.

Here is an example. If I run the code block below, it generates a table grouped by Species and each species has a set of parenthesis next to it, like "Setosa (50)." How do I remove the "(50)" from this string so that it just says "Setosa"? Thanks for your help!

```
library(reactable)
reactable(iris, groupBy = "Species", columns = list(
  Sepal.Length = colDef(aggregate = "count"),
  Sepal.Width = colDef(aggregate = "mean"),
  Petal.Length = colDef(aggregate = "sum"),
  Petal.Width = colDef(aggregate = "max")
))
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with some css sorcery:

First, add some custom class in your reactable call:

```
library(reactable)
reactable(
   iris, 
   groupBy = "Species",
   class = "noParenthesis"
)
```

Then add the following styles to your css file:

```
.noParenthesis .rt-expandable > div {
  height: 21px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

.noParenthesis .rt-expandable > div > span {
    display: table-caption;
    color: transparent;
}

.noParenthesis .rt-expandable > div > span:first-line {
    color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but there is a cleaner way to handle this rather than directly adjusting the CSS. You can write a javascript function in the `grouped` property of the colDef method which defines what is rendered in the cells text when grouped. Here is a simple example from the documentation which achieves the desired result:

```
colDef(
  # Render grouped cells without the row count
  grouped = JS("function(cellInfo) {
    return cellInfo.value
  }")
```

You can see this in use in their [documentation](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#grouped-cell-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is not yet - per the issue here https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/94 from the maintainer `glin`:

> It's not possible today, even with custom JS, but it's been requested before (#33). I'll put it on the list to include for the next release. The usage will probably look something like this: