# How to omit NA's in count when grouping in reactable

Tags: r, reactable

See a simple code

```
library(reactable)
data = data.frame(x = c('a','a','b','b'),
                  values = c(NA,5,3,NA))
reactable(data,
          groupBy = 'x')
```

[image]

Is it possible to count only the lines which aren't NA?

I want to see a(1), b(1) instead

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the NAs with na.omit()

```
data = data.frame(x = c('a','a','b','b'),
                  values = c(NA,5,3,NA))
data = na.omit(data)
reactable(data,
          groupBy = 'x')
```

Comment: I need the NA in the table.

Comment: I am not a reactable power user and a quick glimpse at the documentation does not give an immediate solution. What I can see from the documentation that the number displayed is the count of members. Since you group by x, reactable() will find 2 a's and 2 b's. I have no idea about your usecase. However keeping the NAs in your table makes reactable correctly "group" and count the members per group. What is the benefit of "manipulating" the count of members and when someone expands the group sees additional rows? Maybe what you are looking for is not reactable?

Comment: I need NA values in my data. If I could remove the (2) at all that would also be a nice solution

Comment: Given this SO question this is not possible today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304095/suppress-parenthesis-in-r-reactable-group-aggregation. I keep my fingers crossed for you that this feature will be implemented in a not too distant future.